# Image Texture Size V's Mesh Size

Tags: image

I hope your all having fun been creative.

This is my first post so go easy on me if this has already been asked

I have 3 separate meshes at 3 different size which have had the scale applied and have been unwrapped.  I create a material with a seamless image texture and give each mesh this material. The material appears on each of the 3 meshes at different scales.

Is there a way to have the texture appear at the exact same scale for each mesh size without compromising on the quality of the texture?

I don't want to use the mapping node or scale the UV's down as both methods require a guess and will only give me a similar scale not an exact scale

Thanks

James

Answer (score 1):

One option that may work for you depending on what your objects are, their size, shape, etc. is to join the three objects together, unwrap the combined object so that the scale is exactly the same, and then split the object back into the original 3 parts.

If you ever need to make any tweaks to your texture scale after splitting the objects simply use numeric input so that you can scale each UV map by the exact same amount.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [free addon](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?417608-Addon-Texel-Density-Checker-1-0-6-UPDATE-23-10-17) called Texel Density Checker that will allow you to scale the density to the level you want.

Comment: Sound like this is what I need. I will give it a try, thanks